Using PM2 to start and stop at a particular time
Is it possible to setup pm2 to start a service at a certain time, and then kill it at a certain time.  We have time apps that should only be accessible at certain times, and be turned off the rest of the time.  For example, lets say I have a search API, that I only want to be up and available from 5pm to 9pm; is it possible to set this up fully in pm2?
I'm aware that you can use cron to restart in pm2; I do this with several services in the config.json:
{
    apps: [
        {
            "name" : "space_usage_monitor",
            "script" : "space_usage.py",
            "interpreter" : "python",
            "cron_restart": "30 * * * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI",
            "autorestart": false,
        }
    ]
}

But I don't see anything in the pm2 documentation regarding using cron for start and stops as well.

For doing this, use cron tasks to start and stop pm2 tasks.
pm2 start to start the task and pm2 stop to stop the task.
